# Mapping over array and rendering result

Tags: reactjs, api

I am having difficulties mapping over this object in order to render the data on the API.

Anyone has an idea of what I may be doing wrong?

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    weatherResults: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let obj;
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
     id=52490&appid=${API_KEY}&q=new%20york&cnt=2`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(results => (obj = results))
      .then(() => console.log(obj));
    this.setState({
      weatherResults: this.state.weatherResults
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.weatherResults &&
          this.state.weatherResults.map(data => (
            <div className="container">
              <p>{data.city.name}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `fetch` request is asynchronous, you want to use `setState` when the request has finished to put the response in the component state.

[Looking at one of the sample requests of the API](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22) it looks like you get an object as response, which has `city.name` in it. Instead of having `weatherResults` be an array, you can set it to `null` initially and access `city.name` on it when the object has loaded.

**Example**

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    weatherResults: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=52490&appid=${API_KEY}&q=new%20york&cnt=2`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({
          weatherResults: results
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { weatherResults } = this.state;

    if (weatherResults === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <p>{weatherResults.city.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow... makes so much sense! Thank you so much Tholle!